# Open source .NET platform for classified ads

Tags: asp.net, open-source

I'm looking for an open-source framework for classified ads.  It needs to be .NET-based, but I can pay.

Advanced features not really required - just need to be able to post ads for registered users in a private environment.

In terms of price, anything up to $1,000 is fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I'll write you one this evening for $999 ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft have a starter kit for classifieds:
http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/classifieds

Comment: nope, this is a beta, buggy, doesn't work with II7. anything better ?

Answer (score 1):

MixNP is written in ASP.net C# and is a new addition to codeplex. It is free and open source GPLv3.

Looks good.

https://mixnp.codeplex.com/

Comment: Was just searching for an Open Source Classified in .Net when i accidentally bumped into your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think DotNetNuke would work for you, although it might be a bit of overkill for your intended use case.